# R markdown file takes forever to knit to HTML

Tags: r

I have long complicated functions included in my code.
When I try to knit the Markdown file to HTML document, it takes a very long time and still nothing happens.

I tried to use `cache=TRUE` and updating my R/RStudio but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what else I could try? Thanks

Comment: You need to include the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with the situation. I am using Markdown to show some graphs with notes. When compiling Markdown all the code is executed. Also the computational expensive machine learning. To speed up my process I save the outcomes of my model to dataframes with the `save` function. The file type I use is .Rdata. In the Markdown document I use `load` to load the dataframes in the Markdown environment.